# firebase realtime not work with ganerate apk boundle

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application in which data from the Realtime Firebase database is displayed ... and when I connect the phone with Android Studio and launch the application, it is fully functional and even when I do a build it works completely ..
As for when I do Generating Signed APK, the application works, but the data from the Realtime Firebase database does not appear, which leads to a malfunction in the program and I do not know what is the reason. This is because Android Studio does not give any indication of the presence of an error ... I hope that I clarify the problem well ...

Comment: Add some code in this post so that we can look into it. Also, add what error your app is showing.

Comment: Most likely your signed APK is using ProGuard and that is minifying the property names on your classes so that they don't match with the JSON in the database anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%20proguard and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard

Comment: dont enable the proguard .